# activate/execute python script from html (by url not submit button)

Tags: python, flask

for now I have the python script can extract mysql data and pass to html

- .py script

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.101.141",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="cool_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
      # assume customer looking for product ID 001 item        
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_PRICE  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = '001'")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)    # does get the result I want 

# send result to index.html
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("Myshop.html", myresult = myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

- Myshop.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <p> this is {{myresult}}</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

- task order in pic

[image]

I will put both .py and Myshop.html to WinSCP (on live to public)

**Question: how to trigger .py script by inputing the url like `http://192.168.0.206:8080/english/MyShop.html?ProductID=001`**

that webpage can show different content with my script

---

cuase I see most of the tutorial is using flask submit button

but I want use url pass value and activate my .py to reflash Myshop.html

---

humm, my question is **Question: how to trigger .py script by inputing the url like `http://192.168.0.206:8080/english/MyShop.html?ProductID=001`** , that anyone can type the url `http://......ProductID=001` ,  `http://.......ProductID=007` to load the new page; seems for now, we still need to execute pyscript which is middle step of the  "task order in pic", I want the flow is from first step to the last step
[image]